# Passing an optional argument to a \newenvironment in the second part

Tags: environments

I'm trying to define a new environment as below:

```
\newenvironment{authorquotation}
    {
        \begin{quotation}[1]
    }{
            \begin{flushright}
                \textbf{#1}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{quotation}
    }
```

The problem is that if I use the `#1` in the second part of the definition I get an error. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than this. You don't want a page break between the quotation text and the author name.

Also, if the last line is short you don't want to add vertical space, which would be unsightly.

With `\NewDocumentEnvironment` one can use the argument in the end part of the definition. Some low level trickery is needed to access the width of the last line in order to decide whether adding vertical space or not.

In the example I use two-column format just to make a shorter picture; left are two real examples, right some fake examples that show when the vertical space is actually added.

In case of a page break, two lines of the preceding text will go together the author name.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{authorquotation}{m}
 {\begin{quotation}}
 {\printauthor{#1}\end{quotation}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printauthor}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \abovedisplayskip=\z@
  \abovedisplayshortskip=\z@
  \belowdisplayskip=\z@
  \belowdisplayshortskip=\z@
  $$\global\dimen1=\predisplaysize$$%
  \endgroup
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\textbf{#1}}%
  \nobreak
  \ifdim\dimexpr\dimen1+\dimen0-2\leftmargin+1pc>\linewidth
    \vspace{\medskipamount}%
  \fi
  \noindent\hspace*{\fill}\textbf{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
\end{authorquotation}

\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
\end{authorquotation}

\newpage

\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott]
\end{authorquotation}

\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] xxxxxx
\end{authorquotation}

\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] xxxxxxx
\end{authorquotation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! For clarity I wouldn't use both `\dimen@` and `\dimen0`. Not everyone knows they're the same...

Comment: @campa You're right, I'll fix it. I have to check my glasses.

Answer (score 4):

Save the argument in the 1st part and use that macro in the 2nd.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{authorquotation}[1]
    {
        \def\myauthor{#1}
        \begin{quotation}
    }{
            \begin{flushright}
                \textbf{-\myauthor}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{quotation}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{authorquotation}{Albert Einstein}
Jedenfalls bin ich überzeugt, daß der [Gott] nicht würfelt.
\end{authorquotation}
\end{document}
```

[image]